# How do you encode an ascending sequence as a periodic function?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Say I have a set of numbers in random order $A=\{2.3, 5.6, 1.2, 19.4\}$

I want to save these as a periodic function but where the `natural ordering' of the function is ascending. I could save them as a Fourier function as in:

$f(x) = \sum\limits_n A_n \cos(n \pi x)$

but this gives the wrong ordering. What I mean is it has a natural order.

I could save them as a function:

$f(x) = \sum\limits_n e^{-(x-A_n)^2}$

This would give a function that looks like it has the right ordering. But is not periodic.

By natural ordering I mean that given the function $f$ when trying to get back out the values by some means the natural algorithm would give the values back in ascending order of magnitude.

Comment: Is $A\subset \mathbb Q$?

Comment: No, just positive real numbers.

Comment: perhaps $f(x)=\sum cos(A_n x)$. Not sure how you would recover the values back out again though. No, my mistake that's not periodic. Perhaps its impossible for real numbers.

Comment: Doesn't the order after decoding depend on how you decode? Not only on the method of encoding?